# How to configure Laravel Queue Worker to run forever

Tags: php, laravel, queue, timeout

I am building a web application using laravel.
And I want to run a queue worker.

I used

```
php artisan queue:work
```

But this command runs a worker that only work for 60 seconds as the default timeout is 60sec.

I want to have a queue worker that can run forever.
How can I do that?

I did like this

```
        $schedule->command('queue:work --timeout=60 --stop-when-empty')
            ->everyMinute()
            ->withoutOverlapping();
```

But that gives me timeout error still.

Please help me

Comment: Use [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) to keep queues working

Answer (score 0):

Why `--timeout=60`

You can use

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=0
```

or like this

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --timeout=0')
    ->everyMinute()
    ->withoutOverlapping();
```

Or

```
public $timeout = 0; # in the file
```

or move it to process config [Supervisor Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#supervisor-configuration)